# Keep UI stable running complex queries in background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, asynchronous

**Context :** C# , Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0, WinForms

**Problem :** User Interface hangs when I am running a huge query.

**Explanation :** In my application, I am allowing user to store text file in a specific directory. But before I store the file, I must ensure that the directory and its child directories have no text file. For this reason, I have to enumerate through directory and make sure that the directory tree has no `*.txt` files.

My code is the following:

```
return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();
```

If the directory tree is huge, my UI just hangs, brutally.

The alternative I tried is to to add an `AsParallel()` call to above LINQ Query, but that didn't help me.

How to save my FileChooser window from hanging, when I am running `Directory.GetFiles()`?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm heavily using backgroundworker components in my winforms apps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use tasks for that:

```
private Task<bool> GetFilesAsync(string path)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any(), 
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Then use it with a continuation to handle the result:

```
GetFilesAsync(path).ContinueWith(parentTask => 
{
        // Code which check that parentTask.Exception is null, and then use
        // parentTask.Result
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: It seems that your code won't compile because in StartNew you're using a Func delegate and you're returning nothing. You have to put a `return` before `Directory.GetFiles` otherwise an error will occur : `Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<bool>'`

Comment: Actually no, and you may test it. this is one-line lambda expression, and it returns the value of one-line expression. actually, putting a return, without enclosing it in `{ }` would generate compilation error. If you used LINQ, you should be familiar with such lambdas

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking your method from the UI thread. For this reason, if the method is a time consuming task, the UI freezes and the application seems to be unresponsive.

Use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) thread (as I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192813/702048)) or use the [Task library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to let your method execute asynchronously without freezing the UI.

You can find an example about BackgroundWorker [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

As pointed out by @ShlomiBorovitz (and I agree), the use of BackgroundWorker isn't an elegant solution, because there're too many elements to mantain.
The best solution is, since you're using .NET Framework 4, to use the Tasks library. Less code to mantain and less headaches.

An example about the use of Task library is the following:

```
private Task<bool> SearchFilesAsync(string path)
{
    return Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();
    });

}

private void CheckTxtFile()
{
    string myPath = @"SearchPathHere";
    SearchFilesAsync(myPath).ContinueWith(myTask =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Text file found : {0}", myTask.Result.ToString());
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `Task.Wait(myTask);` is blocking, which means the UI thread would be blocked... same problem as OP. and it won't compile either, because it should be `myTask.Wait();`

Comment: And I fixed the vote down... Still, I wouldn't recommend backgroundworker in .Net 4.0

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz Yes, I noticed now. I know that's not an elegant solution, but it works. It's an alternative.

Comment: I agree (BTW, it's not using the task library, not even in .Net 4.5). But I think that as a less desirable alternative, it should be noted in the end of the answer, not at the start

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz Right. I added a note!

Answer (score 0):

- Add a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) component to the WinForm
- Put the time consuming code in the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event on the BackgroundWorker Thread
- you can use the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event to execute code once the work is completed
- If you like the UI to report on the progress of the long running code, you can make use of the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using backgroundworker in .Net 4.0

Comment: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Tasks, and the whole TPL provide much more elegant, and (more importantly) maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can use background worker in order to perform this task. However, we do not know yet if you want to allow users to use application during the time this task is carried on. If you can answer that, responses would be more suitable for your needs. You could then either continue with threading approach or will have to make something like splash screen to tell users that application is doing something.

Until then, here is something you can do to speed up the search:

First, you really do not want to know how many text files do these directories have. As soon as you find one, your process should return. Take a look at these three methods:

```
///
/// This is similar to what you have been doing. It just uses one less extension method call
///       
private bool SkipDirectory()
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length > 0;
    }

///
/// The EnumerateFileSystemEntries method itself is quicker than GetFiles but Count method makes it slower
///    
private bool SkipDirectoryEnumerableMethod()
    {
        return (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"C:\Program Files", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count() > 0);
    }


    ///
    /// This method only search till the first occurrence of text file is spotted.
    private bool SkipDirectory(string path)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> directoryPaths = null;
        bool hasTextFile = false;

        if (directoryPaths == null)
        {
            directoryPaths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }


        foreach (string directoryPath in directoryPaths)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directoryPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (hasTextFile = (files.Count() > 0))
                break;
        }

        return hasTextFile;
    }
```

On my computer, here are some time span values I saw:

```
Method One: 00:00:00.3300189
Method Two: 00:00:00.3590205
Method Three: 00:00:00.0010001
```

Don't get too excited about third time span. There may be a text file way up higher the directory structure. I do not have a directory set up to properly verify performance but first look does show some interesting thing. For the second method, I am not sure how, but if something more faster than `Count` method can be used, then it does perform better than first one.